# How to make an sql query to a database with json data and using the WHERE operator?

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-boot, mysql-json, jparepository

Good afternoon. Sorry for my English, this is a translation. I am a beginner Java developer. And I use a Mysql database to store movie data. I also have a "genres" column with JSON data. I need to search through the values of this column, extract all the entity data and save it to a collection (list).

```
if (day == DayOfWeek.TUESDAY) {
                List<Film> films = filmService.findFilmsByGenresAndViewed("комедия", false);
                emailService.sendEmailForEveryDayOfWeekWithAttachment(films);
            }
```

I also use JPA Repository methods.

```
@Repository
public interface FilmRepository extends JpaRepository<Film, Long> {
//...
List<Film> findFilmsByGenresAndViewed(String genres, Boolean viewed);
//...
}
```

I tried to make a query like:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM `film` 
WHERE JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`genres`, '$.genres')) LIKE '%genres%';")
    List<Film> findFilmsByGenresAndViewed(String genres, Boolean viewed);
```

But it returns an empty list.
And such a request sends a list with all the movies from the database without searching for a specific genre and viewing:
SELECT
id, filmId, filmName, year, rating, description,   отправляет всю базу
json_extract(genres, '$.genres') AS genres
FROM film;

Comment: can you show an example of what the data in the genres column looks like?

Comment: please always add table and data to your request, but i wonder why you have a genres column a json with genres as node and you are searching for the word genres as text.

Comment: @ysth [{"genre": "боевик"}, {"genre": "комедия"}, {"genre": "приключения"}, {"genre": "фантастика"}] --this is what my data looks like

Comment: @nbk I want to pass as a parameter to search for a string instead of "String genres".

Comment: Your query is wrong. `LIKE '%genres%'` doesn't do what you think it does. It needs to be `LIKE ?` and put the `%` in the string before calling the `findFilmsByGenresAndViewed`. Your current query checks if the `genres` field contains a value with the `String` `genres` instead of what you pass into it. Your extracting seems to be werong as well (as your comment indicate the field is called `genre` and not `genres`). Hence nothing matches, no results.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for your reply. it really is. I also found information that there is no operator for filtering json data in the mysql database. my mentor advised me to switch to Postgresql. here is a link to the information: https://codematcher.com/questions/mysql-json-using-in-statement-json-contains